# https://anysalesforceOrgurl/apexpages/apexcomponents.apexp

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce, dynamic-vf-component

When you go to /apexpages/apexcomponents.apexp from your org instance, it redirects you to a page which shows all visualforce components of your org with component details and usage examples including your custom components.
It automatically fill up your custom components component details too but of course not usage example.We did think that it would be a good cheat sheet for developers in our company.

So, My question is,
Is it possible to fill your custom components' usage tab with an example like originals from somewhere in the org?

[image]

Thanks in advance!